# Magento theme development base vs default

Tags: magento, themes, default, radix

I'm using Magento 1.6. I've created my own theme (mytheme) under base.

So my file structure is app/design/frontend/base/mytheme

I could also develop my theme under app/design/frontend/default/mytheme

Which is best practice? And what are the implications of using base/mytheme rather than default/mytheme?

Cheers,
Eddie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to put your theme in the `base` folder.  The `base` folder is meant to contain the "core" theme that ships with Magento.  It's the ultimate fall back, and the last place a file is looked for.  It was specifically introduced to provide a place where core Magento developers could blow the entire directory away and replace everything (if need be)

To create a theme for Magento, you'll want to create a theme folder in your design package

```
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme
```

Then, in the admin go to

```
System -> Configuration -> Design
```

and enter `mytheme` in the `Default` field.  Your theme will now the the "default" place Magento looks for files.  If it doesn't find one, it will fall back on what it finds in the `base` folder.

Comment: Thanks Alan - so, by putting mytheme under base, Mage has to look 1st thro all the app/design/frontent/default/ themes before falling back to find my theme under base? That makes sense - appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

I do disagree with the solution of Mr Storm.

ref: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

Those documents recommend You avoid to use the package default (as the base package too)

You have to creating Your own package 'mytheme' and to define a theme 'default'

ref: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

> "Please ignore legacy Magento instructions and tutorials that instruct
>   you to create your custom theme inside of the default design package,
>   or to edit files in the default/default directory directly.
>
> Rather,
>   the method that affords the best upgrade path for your theme and the
>   most protection from accidental changes is **to create a new designpackage** 
>   and to create your custom theme inside of there."

So the correct answer is

app/design/frontend/**your-package**/default

Do NOT use:

app/design/frondend/default/**your-theme**